A wireless mouse working with Bluetooth connection, but not working with 2.4G connection
I got a new mouse and have been trying to get it to work on Ubuntu 23.10 (and 24.04 now) in the 2.4G connection mode (and it does not). The mouse works fine with Bluetooth, and it works in both modes when I use it with a Windows (10) machine, which has the driver file "mouhid.sys". Any help or advice?
If it helps, the command lsusb gives:
...
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 3151:3020 YICHIP Wireless Device
...

This vanishes when I turn the mouse off or pull the USB Receiver out of the computer, so I assume it's the wireless mouse.
It's this mouse: https://www.amazon.com/Wireless-Bluetooth-Mouse-Rechargeable-Bluetooth5-2/dp/B0BPCW5CS6?th=1
UPDATE: sometimes it works now in the 2.4G mode; sometimes not... I haven't found a pattern to it's functionality yet.
